# overheating in ubuntu but not in windows

Tags: 12.10, overheating, fan

my sensors show 70°C coretemp. (sometimes up to 80°C)

```
lm-sensors  sudo sensors-detect yesyes...:

Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

fancontrol->sudo pwmconfig:

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I cleaned the fan and renewed the thermalpaste (it was darkish and hard, looked pretty grilled)

reducing cpu to 800mhz with jupiter power works, but its not nice, since I use blender for modeling.

the fan makes noise, but there is almost no air coming out(but the air is very hot)
what can I do to protect my Acer Aspire Laptop from grilling?

since on windows7 there was never a overheating problem, I suppose its something with ubuntu, right?

thank you for help

Comment: I see its a common problem, please close.

Comment: It isn't overheating; 70 degrees is pretty normal under load.  90 is where you should start to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm....I guess check out your power settings, possibly even in your bios but most likely in Linux.  Make sure that it IS actively monitoring temps and controlling fan speeds and cooling.

It's possible that a video controller or your chipset or something is not using the correct driver in linux.  If this is the case, I'd say start by going into Software Sources in Ubuntu and seeing about using different video drivers (like for NVidia cards, there's at least five different sources for drivers and only one or two of them are NVidia).

A chipset driver might make sense as this is where your power management tends to take place.  It's possible that your Acer may requires proprietary drivers for it's power management features.

Comment: Can be, but i thought that fans always are controlled by the bios.

Comment: yes and no.  They usually are, but really only CPU and case fans and there's usually not a lot of options so a lot of manufacturers like to use their own proprietary stuff, at least for monitoring.  The error at the end of this post might indicate that the hardware in his acer may not be supported by pwm or that a setting in the bios has the bios controlling power management rather than letting the OS do it.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now ;). Desktops cases have fans too and these need to be controlled by a driver (I have a laptop thats why I am confused). Thanks, I will vote up your answer.

Comment: Thanks!  yeah, the motherboard actually diminishes power going to the fans from the power supply as part of power management so if power management were disabled altogether, your fans would be running at full speed all of the time.

Comment: fans are controlled by the hardware/ACPI BIOS; no driver is needed.